# unexplained string from bash loop

Tags: bash

I have some file in the name of OBS_SURFACE1**, OBS_SURFACE101, OBS_SURFACE103. Yes, there indeed is a file named OBS_SURFACE1**, which I guess where the problem arise. I wrote a bash script which has:

```
for fil in ` ls OBS_DOMAIN1?? `
do
  echo "appending" $fil
done
```

The first value of fil will be OBS_SURFACE1** OBS_SURFACE101 OBS_SURFACE103, the second OBS_SURFACE101. While I expect the first to be OBS_SURFACE1**. If there is no OBS_SURFACE1** file, there would be no problem. Why is that then?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: Also, you're quoting the thing that doesn't need to be quoted -- the word `appending`, which can't ever expand to anything but itself -- and not quoting the thing that *must* be quoted, the `$fil` expansion, meaning that its result gets string-split and glob-expanded.

Answer (score 3):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)! It will only ever lead to problems. Use a glob instead:

```
for fil in OBS_DOMAIN1??
do
  echo "appending $fil"
done
```

The problem that you are experiencing stems from the fact that the output of `ls` contains `*`, which are being expanded by bash. Note that I have also quoted the whole string to be `echo`ed, which protects against word splitting inside the loop. See the links provided in the comments above for more details on that.

As pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413197/unexplained-string-from-bash-loop/26413256#comment41474512_26413256) (thanks [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)), you may also want to enable `nullglob` before your loop like this: `shopt -s nullglob`. This will mean that if there are no files that match the pattern, the loop will not run at all, rather than running once with `$fil` taking the literal value `OBS_DOMAIN1??`. Another option would be to check whether the file exists in within the loop, for example using:

```
if [[ -e "$fil" ]]; then
  echo "appending $fil"
fi
```

or the more compact `[[ -e "$fil" ]] && echo "appending $fil"`.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning the `nullglob` shopt option, or putting a `[[ -e "$fil" ]]` check in the loop to handle the case where a lack of matches results in the glob expression itself being returned.

Answer (score 0):

yet another way of doing this :

```
echo appending OBS_DOMAIN1??
```

this will list all files , no loop needed.

Comment: The output of this would be "appending file1 file2 file3", rather than "appending file1" "appending file2" "appending file3" on separate lines.